# Can't get jQuery (or javascript) pass my variable to the next page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm modify-ing a PHP script which pass variable to the next PHP page but via a jQuery (or javascript) script instead of using form with POST method. I read the whole jQuery (or javascript) script and learn how the author pass his variable to next PHP page, then add my variable to the script just like what he does, but no matter what I do, the damn script only pass his variable, it won't do anything with my variable. I'm confused and can't understand why. Here are my code:

HTML form which let user input my variable (account and password)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>[ChipVN] PHP Image Uploader 4.0 - chiplove.9xpro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<script  type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery.js?v=3.1"></script>
<script  type="text/ecmascript" src="script.js?v=3.1"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Picasa Image Uploader</h1>
        <div class="description">yurivn.net</div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="option">            
            <div class="rows">
                <span>Nhập thông tin tài khoản google:</span><br/>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <span>Tên tài khoản: </span><input type="text" id="account" value="myaccount" /><br/>
                <span>Mật khẩu: </span><input type="password" id="password" value="mypassword" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rows method uploadfile">
                 <div class="upload">
                    <span>Nhấn Browser để chọn file upload</span>
                    <div id="embed"></div>
                 </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rows method transload">
                <span>Nhập link ảnh vào để transload</span> 
                <div><textarea class="links"></textarea></div>
                <span class="note">(Mỗi link ảnh 1  dòng, có hỗ trợ link ảnh trong thẻ [IMG])</span>
                <div><input type="button" class="button" value="Transload" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rows warning">Trình duyệt của bạn phải bật javascript để sử dụng công cụ này</div>
        </div><!--/.option-->
    </div>
</div><!--/#wrapper-->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="body">
        <div id="result"></div>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <div id="list" style="display:none">
            <div class="format">
                <a href="javascript:;" name="direct">Link trực tiếp</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" name="bbcode">Chèn vào Forum</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" name="html">Chèn vào website</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" name="removesub">Remove sub</a>
            </div>
            <div><textarea class="links" onclick="this.select()"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jQuery (or javascript) script - passing variable to the next PHP page: the author's variable is server, resize, wartermark, logo, mine is account and password

```
/**
 * c-Image Uploader, use to upload image to some services (picasa, imageshack, imgur ...etc)
 *
 * @project     Image Uploader
 * @author      Phan Thanh Cong <chiplove.9xpro@gmail.com>
 * @since       June 17, 2010
 * @version     3.1
 * @since       March 8, 2012
 * @copyright   chiplove.9xpro
*/

// Default options
var options = {
    watermark:  0, // 1 or 0
    logo:       3, // danh sách logo trong file upload
    resize:     0, // tương tự logo
    server:     3, // trong file upload và index
    format:     'bbcode',   //danh sách các link trả về đc format theo bbcode, html và link trực tiếp
    removesub:  0, // dành cho link của imageshack.us
    method:     'uploadfile', // uploadfile/ transload
        account:        'myaccount',
        password:       'mypassword'
}

$(function(){
    renderUploader();
    clearlist();    
    $(".warning").hide();

    // set default
    $('input:radio[name=watermark]').removeAttr("checked").filter('[value='+getWatermark()+']').attr('checked', true);

    $('input:radio[name=logo]').removeAttr("checked").filter('[value='+getLogo()+']').attr('checked', true);

    $("#resize option").filter('[value='+getResize()+']').attr('selected', true);

    $("#server option").filter('[value='+getServer()+']').attr('selected', true);

    $(".method").hide();
    $("."+getMethod()).slideDown();

    // change value 
    $('input:radio').click(function(){
        $.cookie($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
        renderUploader();   
    }); 
    $("#resize, #server, #account, #password").change(function(){
        $.cookie($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
        renderUploader();   
    });

    $("#uploadfile").click(function(){
        $(".transload").hide();
        $(".uploadfile").slideDown();
        $.cookie('method', 'uploadfile');
        renderUploader();   
        clearlist();
    });
    $("#transload").click(function(){
        $(".uploadfile").hide();
        $(".transload").slideDown();
        $.cookie('method', 'transload');
        clearlist();
    });

    $(".format a").click(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if(name != 'removesub') {
            $.cookie('format', name);
        }
        else {
            var removesub = getRemovesub() == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            $.cookie('removesub', removesub);
        }
        showList();
    });

    // transload click
    $(".transload .button").click(function(){
        transload();
    });

});

function getRemovesub() {
    return $.cookie('removesub') == null ? options.removesub : $.cookie('removesub');
}
function getFormat() {
    return $.cookie('format') == null ? options.format : $.cookie('format');
}
function getMethod() {
    return $.cookie('method') == null ? options.method : $.cookie('method');
}
function getWatermark() {
    return $.cookie('watermark') == null ? options.watermark : $.cookie('watermark');
}
function getLogo() {
    return $.cookie('logo') == null ? options.logo : $.cookie('logo');
}
function getResize() {
    return $.cookie('resize') == null ? options.resize : $.cookie('resize');
}
function getServer() {
    return $.cookie('server') == null ? options.server : $.cookie('server');
}
function getAccount() {
    return $.cookie('account') == null ? options.account : $.cookie('account');
}
function getPassword() {
    return $.cookie('password') == null ? options.password : $.cookie('password');
}


function renderUploader() {
    var html = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="75" height="25"> \
        <param name="movie" value="upload.swf" /> \
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> \
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> \
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />  \
        <param name="watermark" value="'+getWatermark()+'" /> \
        <param name="logo" value="'+getLogo()+'" /> \
        <param name="resize" value="'+getResize()+'" /> \
        <param name="server" value="'+getServer()+'" /> \
                <param name="account" value="'+getAccount()+'" /> \
                <param name="password" value="'+getPassword()+'" /> \
        <embed name="flashplayer" src="upload.swf" flashvars="'
            +'watermark='+getWatermark()
            +'&logo='+getLogo()
            +'&resize='+getResize()
            +'&server='+getServer()
            +'&account='+getAccount()
            +'&password='+getPassword()                    
        +'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="75" height="25" wmode="transparent"></embed> \
        </object>';
    $("#embed").html(html); 
}

var iloadPosition = 0;
var iload = false;
var loadInterval = 0;
function loading(status) {
    iloadPosition = 0;
    if(status == false) {
        iload = false;
        if(document.getElementById('process') != null) {
            $('#process').html(''); 
            $('#status').html('');
        }
        clearInterval(loadInterval);
        loadInterval = 0;
    }
    else {
        iload = true;
        $('#status').html('Loading <span id="process"></span>');
        if( loadInterval <= 0) {
            loadInterval = setInterval('iloading();',160);
        }
    }
}
function iloading() {
    if (iload) {
       // var icon = new Array('|', '/', '-', '\\');
        var icon = new Array('.', '..', '...', '....');
        //var icon = new Array('|', '||', '|||', '||||', '|||||', '||||||');
        iloadPosition = iloadPosition >= icon.length ? 0 : iloadPosition;
        $('#process').html(icon[iloadPosition]);
        iloadPosition++;
    } 
}

function responseStatus(msg) {
    if (msg == 'Done!') {
        loading(false);
        showList();
    }
    $('#status').html(msg);
}

// hàm hiển thị ảnh
function displaypic(name, url) {
    $("#result").append('<div><span class="name">'+name+'</span><input type="text" class="link" onclick="this.select()" value="'+url+'" /></div>');
    showList();
}
// xóa list link trả về
function clearlist() {  
    $('#status').html('');
    $("#result").html('');
    $("#list .links").val('');
}
function showList() {

    $("#list").slideDown();
    var code;
    if (getFormat() == 'html') {
        code = new Array('<img src="', '" />');
    } 
    else if (getFormat() == 'bbcode') {
        code = new Array('[IMG]', '[/IMG]');
    } 
    else {
        code = new Array('', '');
    }
    var links = "";
    $("#result .link").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if(getRemovesub()) {
            url = removesub(url);
            $(this).val(url);
        }
        if(url.substring(0, 4) != 'http') {
            return;
        }
        links += code[0] + url + code[1] +"\n";
    });
    $("#list .links").slideDown().val(links);
}

function removesub(url) {
    re = /(https?:\/\/)([^\.]*?)(\.imageshack\.us\/)(img[^\.\/]*)(.*?\.)(jpg|png|bmp|gif|jpeg)/ig;
    if(m = re.exec(url)) {
        if (getRemovesub() == 0) {
            url = url.replace(m[1] + m[2], m[1] + 'a');
        } else {
            url = url.replace(m[1] + m[2], m[1] + m[4]); 
        }
    }
    return url;
}
/****** TRANSLOAD ****/
function getInputLinks() {
    var text = $(".transload .links").val();
    var re = /.*?(\[IMG\])?(https?[^\\\n[]+)(\[\/IMG\])?/ig;
    var m;
    var links = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    while (m = re.exec(text)) {
       links[i++] = $.trim(m[2]);
    }
    return links;
}
function doTransload(id, links) {
    var stt = id + 1;
    var url = links[id];
    $.ajax({
        data: "id=453&action=test",
        url: 'upload.php',  
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(msg){
            displaypic(stt, msg);
            if(stt < links.length) {
                doTransload(stt, links);
            }
            else {
                responseStatus('Done!');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Có lỗi, vui lòng thử lại");
        }
    });
}
function transload() {
    clearlist();
    var links = getInputLinks();
    if(links.length == 0) {
        alert('Bạn cần phải nhập đường dẫn ảnh');
        return;
    }
    loading();
    doTransload(0, links);
}
```

The next PHP page: I have `echo 'image=' . var_export($_REQUEST, true);` at the end of the PHP script to print the variable it get after choosing something to upload, my variable are not here.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh');

session_start();

define('DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
include DIR . 'library/ChipVN/Loader.php';
\ChipVN\Loader::registerAutoLoad();


// fiter
$params = array('server', 'resize', 'watermark', 'logo', 'account', 'password');
foreach($params as $param)
{
    $name = $param . 'id';
    $data = intval($_REQUEST[$param]);
    if($data < 0) 
    {
        $data = 0;
    }
    ${$name} = $data;
}

##################### START CONFIG #######################

$sitename = 'website';

/**
 * Tạo và CHMOD folder này sang 777
*/
$tempdir = DIR . 'temp/';

// danh sách logo
$logolist = array(
    1 => 'logo1.png', 
    2 => 'logo2.png',
    3 => 'logo3.png',
);
// Nếu logo yêu cầu ko có trong danh sách thì dùng logo1.png 
$default['logo'] = 'logo1.png';

// vị trí logo (right bottom, right center, right top, left top, .v.v.)
$logoPosition = 'rb';



// kích cỡ resize
$resizelist = array(
    0   => 0, // ko resize
    1   => 100, 
    2   => 150,
    3   => 320,
    4   => 640,
    5   => 800,
    6   => 1024
);
//$default['resize'] = 800;
$default['resize'] = 0;


##################### END CONFIG #######################



$watermark = $watermarkid > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;

$logoPath = DIR . 'logo/' . (in_array($logoid, array_keys($logolist)) ? $logolist[$logoid] : $default['logo']);

$resizeWidth = in_array($resizeid, array_keys($resizelist)) ? $resizelist[$resizeid] : $default['resize'];


if($_FILES['Filedata'] AND !$_FILES['Filedata']['error'])
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $imagePath = $tempdir . $sitename .date('dmY'). '.jpg');
    $isUpload = TRUE;
}
else if($url = trim($_POST['url']))
{
    $isUpload = FALSE;
    \ChipVN\Image::leech($url, $imagePath = $tempdir . $sitename . date('dmY').'.jpg');
}


// resize
if($resizeWidth > 0)
{
    \ChipVN\Image::resize($imagePath, $resizeWidth, 0);
}
// watermark
if($watermark)
{
    \ChipVN\Image::watermark($imagePath, $logoPath, $logoPosition);
}

switch($serverid)
{
    case 1: 
        $service = 'Imageshack';
        break;
    case 2:
        $service = 'Imgur';
        break;
    case 3:
        $service = 'Picasa';
        break;
    case 4:
        $service = 'Flickr';
        break;  
    default:
        $service = 'Picasa';            
}

$uploader = \ChipVN\Image_Uploader::factory($service);

switch($service)
{
    case 'Imageshack':
        /**
         * Không bắt buộc đăng nhập
         * Có thể đăng nhập hoặc ko. Tuy nhiên nên tham khảo quy định của ImageShack ở đây http://imageshack.us/content.php?page=rules
         * Xóa comment "#" ở bên dưới nếu muốn up vào account của bạn
        **/
        # $uploader->login('your user', 'your pass');
        break;

    case 'Imgur':
        /**
         * Không bắt buộc đăng nhập
         * Có thể đăng nhập hoặc ko, nhưng ảnh mà ko up vào account thì có thể bị xóa sau 1 thời gian.
         * Account thường chỉ up đc 225 ảnh. Xem thông tin upgrade lên PRO tại đây https://imgur.com/register/upgrade
         * Xóa comment "#" ở bên dưới nếu muốn up vào account của bạn
        **/
        # $uploader->login('your user', 'your pass');
        break;  

    case 'Picasa':
        /**
         * Picasa bắt buộc phải đăng nhập 
         * AlbumID lấy ở link RSS trong album (ko biết thì tự tìm hiểu ở google)
         * Phần albumID có thể set 1 array('id1', 'id2'); Code sẽ tự động lấy ngẫu nhiên 1 album trong số đó để upload vào.
         * Nếu ko setAlbumID thì code sẽ up vào album default của picasa 
         * Giới hạn upload ca Picasa xem tại đây: https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/43879?hl=vi
         * Nếu ko dùng AlbumID thì thêm dấu # ở trước
        */
        $uploader->login($accountid, $passwordid);
        #$uploader->setAlbumID('album id của bạn');

        break;  
}

if(!$imagePath)
{
    die('Mising an image');
}
$url = $uploader->upload($imagePath);

if(file_exists($imagePath)) 
{
    unlink($imagePath);
}

if($isUpload)
{
    echo 'image=' . var_export($_REQUEST, true);
}
else
{
    echo $url;
}
```

Notice:

- There are some Vietnamese comments in the script, if it get in your way, please tell me, I will edit my post
- Those scripts use some of other classes and library, if you need the full code, please download here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/c5pen43ggl9444j/ImageUploader.rar

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to pass the account username and password inputs from your HTML form to  your PHP script.  This is the JavaScript that is AJAXing data right now:

```
$.ajax({
    data: "id=453&action=test",
    url: 'upload.php',  
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
```

The "data" property is what is actually being POSTed onto your upload.php file.  Even though you identified your AJAX type as POST, you're current data transmission is shown in a GET format.

You'll need something like the following to adhere to a POST transmission format:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {username: my_username, password: my_password},
    url: 'upload.php',  
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
```

I looked over the rest of your JavaScript and it looks like there is nothing grabbing the user inputs as of right now.  So before you can use the edited AJAX code above, you'll need to put the following into your JavaScript before the above.

```
var my_username = document.getElementById("account").value;
var my_password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

The above tells JavaScript to take the values from your username and password inputs and set them as the "my_username" and "my_password" variables (which will eventually be passed to the AJAX call and then sent to your PHP page).

You also seem to be missing code in your PHP file that grabs the POST values.  You can grab them using the following format:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

You can then do with the variables as you please.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).  It gives you step by step instructions on what you are trying to accomplish